# How can I get Mathematica to include size information in exported SVG?

Tags: export, svg-format

When I use `Export` to export graphics in SVG format, the exported file contains no `width` `height` or `viewBox` attributes, so that the resulting files don't "scale" at all, which is the whole point.

Is there a way to get `Export` to include size information in exported SVGs?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "scale". If I open an SVG exported from Mathematica in IE9, it definitely "scales" when I zoom up and down using the mousewheel. Did you have something other than that in mind?

Comment: @Verbeia: Scaling with the window when, for example, its CSS is `height:100%; width:100%`.

Answer (score 3):

I just answered a related question where I posted an `SVG` export function that fixes the scaling problems. At least that's what I conclude from the following tests:

1. First load the definitions for `svgExport` from the [answer linked here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25835/245).
2. Create a plot and export it like this:

   ```
   p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];    
   svgExport["plot.svg", p, AspectRatio -> Full]    
   (* ==> "plot.svg" *)
   ```
3. Create a `HTML` file that embeds the `SVG` as shown:

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
     <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
       <title>SVG scaling</title>
     </head>

     <body>
       <h1>SVG scaling</h1>

   <object style="width:400px;height:400px;" data="plot.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>

     </body>
   </html>
   ```

The page displays as follows in a browser:

[image: screen shot]

The scaling is completely determined by the `width` and `height` values in the `<object>` tag. If you leave out the `AspectRatio` option in `svgExport`, the overall scaling still works based on the `<object>` settings, but the aspect ratio of the graphics is always preserved so that there will be additional white space.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica does not put information about width and height into `<svg>` tag, but the first group contains a filled rectangle (`<rect fill ...>`) that does have width and height.

You may extract width and height attributes from that `<rect>` and assign them to the root `<svg>` element.

Comment: This doesn't generally work. It relies on a `<rect>` that only gets created when the graphic is exported with default background. If you add the `Export` option `Background -> None` there is no such `<rect>`.