# Why are the elements of plots separated in exported PDFs?

Tags: graphics, export, pdf-format

When I export a plot to a PDF with something like

```
Export["test.pdf", Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], "PDF"]
```

I get a file in which the axes have been separated from the rest of the plot in some editors and viewers (e.g., [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/)):

[image]

Why is this happening? Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: This is certainly platform related... Which Mathematica version and operating system are you using? (Well the OS one can guess... :)

Comment: Oh and another thing... have you tried opening the pdf in another viewer? A possible workaround could be to export to some other vector forma (svg, ps,...) and try to convert from there. Also, there are 2 other ways to export plots: 1) "Save Graphic As..." from the context menu and 2) "Save Selection As..." from "Edit". It's always a delight to see the different graphics these 3 methods produce!

Comment: *Mathematica* 9.0.0.0; OS 10.8.2.

Comment: @sebhofer: In some viewers it looks fine. Exporting to SVG is not an option. The whole reason for exporting to PDF is actually that it's the only way to end up with a decent SVG. *Mathematica's* SVG export omits [size](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17919/37) and [font](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17921/37) information.

Comment: Unfortunately the pdf export is pretty flawed too...

Comment: @sebhofer: Yes, the lesser of two evils; or at least the more easily repaired.

Comment: If the PDF displays fine in Adobe Reader but not in the editor you use, then this is a problem with the graphics editor, not Mathematica's PDF export.  These plots open fine in Illustrator.

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't know... I would trust most pdf viewers more than Mathematica's pdf export.

Comment: @sebhofer: Agreed. *Mathematica* is the culprit here. I have no problem opening any other PDFs.

Comment: @sebhofer The comparison here is between mainstream PDF viewers such as Adobe Reader, Preview, etc. and OmniGraffle (not M and OmniGraffle).  If the former all display it differently than OmniGraffle, then there must be something wrong with OmniGraffle.

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't mean to be nitpicking here, but not all viewers might be equally strict with the implementation of the pdf standard, so your conclusion might not be correct. However, it seems that Acrobat Reader is actually a reference implementation (at least up to pdf version 1.7). Nevertheless, I have seen Mathematica mess up the pdf export too many times, at least on Linux. So I'm really not surprised by the above picture.

Comment: Did you send the PDF to the Omnigroup? They're a pretty responsive bunch and I wouldn't be surprised if you get an answer.

Comment: @DavidSkulsky: Good point. Will do.

Comment: @sebhofer If that is the case (i.e. that some viewers automatically correct a broken PDF and some don't), perhaps re-saving the PDF (completely reprocessing it) will fix the problem.  It's worth trying even if the PDF is not really broken.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yup that is definitely worth a try!

Comment: I finally have time to look this up and post this.  There's a very nice open source tool that can reprocess PDFs for you, but unfortunately it's a bit difficult to get the older version that still supports this functionality.  Get Multivalent from [here](http://code.google.com/p/pdfsizeopt/downloads/detail?name=Multivalent20060102.jar&can=2&q=) (not from the official site---latest version is no good), and follow the instructions [here](http://multivalent.sourceforge.net/Tools/pdf/Compress.html) to reprocess the PDF. If you have Acrobat, it's simpler to try 'optimizing' the PDF using it first.

Comment: Does this fix the problem?  I do not have OmniGraffle to test.  All four software I tried display the PDFs correctly (and all four use independent engines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in OmniGraffle, but you can avoid it (at least for display) by *copy/pasting* the PDF (from the Finder) rather than Opening it.

Comment: It looks to me like that just embeds a PDF as a single monolithic, uneatable object.

Comment: Yes, that's true - it's uneditable (and uneatable, too)... I'll bet you an up/down vote it's an OmniGraffle bug though... :)

Comment: I'd agree. This won't answer it for me though. I've got to open it in a different viewer, save it, and then open that in OmniGraffle, where I can edit it. I've sent the file to Omni.

Comment: Can you start the answer with "This looks like a bug in OmniGraffle, but you can avoid it (at least for display) by...". Then I'll accept.