# Embed Code Into Image

Tags: export, image, metadata

I often export images(plots, matrix, arrays, etc..) from mathematica which I end up putting in word documents or uploading to the web.  The problem is that I often lose the original code and I am left only with the image representing the original output.

I was thinking/considering of using one of the libraries discusses here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335220/embed-text-into-png but was wondering what the Mathematica community new of any functionality built into Mathematica allowing to embed text(the code) into the image.

Comment: It certainly is possible — see [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/632/5) and  [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/633/5) where the notebook is embedded into a GIF. That's not a solution to your question though, since the _image_ in those GIFs are meaningless. My point is that it is possible to embed the information you seek in images... [perhaps a lot more](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/17/the-story-behind-the-matlab-default-image/). However, you might lose it all if your application X does any sort of compression.

Comment: @rm-rf Well I generally speaking use either open office format or something .doc the old Microsoft format.  I am going to look into whether or not they compress images by default.

Comment: [Any use?](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/07/08/doing-spy-stuff-with-mathematica/)

Comment: @cormullion Thank you for the link.  After seeing that I feel fairly certain that there is some way to work around the compression issues, but I am slightly concerned how that might affect the final size

Comment: If you export as e.g. EMF, the code representing the graphic will be embedded into the file. Of course, this isn't the same as the code used to *generate* the graphic, but I'm sure you can find a way to store some extra information in that `Graphics` expression.

Comment: @OleksandrR. `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> Style[#0, Transparent]] &[]` :D

Comment: @rm-rf How did they manage to encode the text into the image for this example?  http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/626/is-there-a-way-to-facilitate-the-copypaste-process-for-code-samples/632  I see the decoding code, but don't understand the exact encoding process without a link to some data.

Comment: @Liam I guess Sjoerd didn't post the encoding code, but belisarius' answer has it. In any case, those weren't actual questions/answers... they were just some ideas thrown around in meta discussions, so don't expect fully fleshed out code :)

Comment: @Liam In the linked article, Jon managed to store 70K ASCII characters in a 450x450 image, and he's stealing space rather than adding it, so the image is the same size, although slightly degraded. You could squeeze more text in if it was compressed.

Comment: If image is intended for web and HTML only, you can write its code in the `alt` or `title` attribute of `img` tag.

Comment: PNG and JPEG also support metadata, so you could write your code there. Interesting Q by the way:)

Comment: @Ajasja A quick experiment suggests that Mathematica doesn't export metadata to JPG files, but can import it from JPG files.

Comment: @cormullion Aaa, same story as with `HDF5` Attributes...

Comment: What goal do you want to achieve with the compatibility table you added? The criteria seem to be chosen rather haphazardly.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Well if nothing else, there are getting to be enough answers, that it is quiet difficult to tell what functionality each answer delivers.  The table can definitely be changed, but I think most people (well at least myself) care most about what applications the images can reliably import images and export the images and extract the code.  The boxes by no means need to be either `Yes`/`No`, I was thinking that could even could contain footnotes or stars `*` explaining what image formats you can convert between and export to keep the data.  Compatibility > Hackiness of answers

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Would it be a bad ideas to edit the questions with the compatibility table myself?  Also continuing on the last comment, I think whatever format allows people to most easily to import and export images, is probably the best solution.  If the only way to get that level of compatibly is encoding a couple pixel high strip to the output image, then I am beginning to lean in that direction.

Comment: If you want to make such a table I suggest you put it in a summary section at the end of your question. I'd say it's rather uncommon, though sometimes in questions where efficiency is an issue you see timing tables pop up.

Comment: I also suggest making a summary table at the end for all answers (after the initial flurry of answers) instead of updating it for each one and making minor edits, unnecessarily pushing it closer to a CW

Comment: @rm-rf I think the table formatting is about there.  I wanted clickable links, so I had to do some rather weird formatting to add the links.  What do you mean by CW?

Comment: @Liam CW is "Community Wiki" mode, which doesn't accrue any points for votes. When a user edits their post too many times (10, to be precise), the system sets the question and answers to this mode so that people don't keep pushing their question to the front page (every edit pushes it to the front page). In any case, I'm sure you've noticed by now that tables are not supported (especially clickable ones) and all hacks are  eventually bound to break (for instance, when you change font/fontsize).

Comment: The current entries in the table are incorrect. As far as I know Photoshop doesn't read or write SVG, so the "yes" in Jens' column is incorrect. SVG can also not be converted to other formats without losing Jens' info. Another incorrect entry. My solution allows for about 4GB of code, which I would say is endless for all means and purposes. So the "no "there would seem incorrect. It can also be converted from docx (see my update).

Comment: I'd suggest to add a row "image can be edited without losing metadata".

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries You are correct.  I am in the process of editing it right now therefore several of them are wrong.  I would prefer not to push it into a community wiki by editing it to many times.  Is there a place I can post the table so other people can edit it without pushing into a Community Wiki?  We could later copy back over once the answers are done and the page is mostly done.  I was thinking Google docs maybe?

Comment: Could use a temporary answer and mark it as such by an appropriate heading.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries If I edit my own question one more time (total 10 times) I believe it is going to push it into a Community Wiki.  Do you mind deleting the compatibility table in the original question and just putting a link to the answer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25759#answer-25900  I am in the process of modifying and updating the compatibly table now.

Comment: I believe that all edits count towards CW, so that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here a quick hack for PNG images. As [its Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) shows the format works with coded *chunks* and you can make up and insert chunk types yourself. I'm not sure how safe it is to add beyond the official end of file marker as Simon Woods suggests in his answer. It seems like a breach of the standard to me.

The following code, which more closely seems to follow the PNG standard, inserts a "mmAc" (Mathematica code) chunk before the end of file marker. A chunk consists of a four byte length coding, a four byte chunk name, the content itself and a four byte CRC32 check.

```
ClearAll[myGraphicsCode];

SetAttributes[myGraphicsCode, HoldFirst];

myGraphicsCode[gfun_, opts__: {}] :=
  Module[{img, pngData, extraData},
    img = Image[gfun, FilterRules[opts, Options[Image]]];
    pngData = Drop[ImportString[ExportString[img, "PNG"], "Binary"], -12];
    extraData = ToCharacterCode@Compress@Defer@gfun;
    Join[pngData, 
         IntegerDigits[Length[extraData], 256, 4], 
         ToCharacterCode@"mmAc", 
         extraData, 
         IntegerDigits[
           Hash[StringJoin["mmAc", FromCharacterCode@extraData], "CRC32"], 
           256, 4
         ], 
         {0, 0, 0, 0, 73, 69, 78, 68, 174, 66, 96, 130}
    ]
  ]
```

Please note that the specific capitalization of the chunk name used here is essential.

Generating the image:

```
Export[
  "C:\\Users\\Sjoerd\\Desktop\\Untitled-1.png", 
   myGraphicsCode[
     Plot[Sin[ x^2], {x, -3, 3}], 
     ImageResolution -> 100
   ], 
   "Binary"
]
```

Posting it here:

[image]

Getting the plot information from the image posted above:

```
Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bEXu.png", "Binary"] /. 
   {___, a : PatternSequence[_, _, _, _], 109, 109, 65, 99, b___} :> 
  Uncompress@FromCharacterCode@Take[{b}, FromDigits[{a}, 256]]
```

> Plot[Sin[x^2], {x, -3, 3}]

Some image editors respect the chunk, others don't. Here is a vandalized version of the above file (done in MS Paint):

[image]

It still works:

```
Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA1CS.png", "Binary"] /. 
    {___, a : PatternSequence[_, _, _, _], 109, 109, 65, 99, b___} :> 
  Uncompress@FromCharacterCode@Take[{b}, FromDigits[{a}, 256]]
```

> Plot[Sin[x^2], {x, -3, 3}]

I tested it in Photoshop 10.0.1, but it unfortunately didn't work there.

---

**UPDATE 1**

As requested by Stefan, here a step by step explanation how it's done. I'll use an update version of the above code that I used to investigate ajasja's suggestion of using standard public chunck names instead of custom ones. This to see whether Photoshop respects those (it doesn't either).

Attributes `HoldFirst` is set so that I can enter plot code without having it evaluated prematurily.

```
ClearAll[myGraphicsCode];
SetAttributes[myGraphicsCode, HoldFirst];
```

I want to be able to flexible set the bitmap properties of the plot. So I allowed for the options of `Image` to be passed through my function.

```
myGraphicsCode[gfun_, opts__: {}] :=
 Module[{img, pngData, extraData},
  img = Image[gfun, FilterRules[opts, Options[Image]]];
```

I use `ExportString` to export the image as a PNG to string data. This saves me temporary file handling. The image is immediately imported again, but now as a list of bytes. Mathematica closes the PNG with a standard 12 byte sequence ({0,0,0,0} (data length)+"IEND"+CRC). I chop it off and will add it back later on.

```
  pngData = Drop[ImportString[ExportString[img, "PNG"], "Binary"], -12];
```

Here the stuff for a "iTXt" chunk (see the [W3 PNG definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11textinfo) for details):

```
  extraData = 
   Join[ToCharacterCode@"iTxtMathematica code", {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    ToCharacterCode@Compress@Defer@gfun];
```

I wrapped the plot code with `Defer` so that it won't be evaluated once recovered from a file's meta data. `Compress` converts it to a safe character range and does some compression.

Putting it all together. `IntegerDigits[value, 256, 4]` turns value into 4 bytes. 4 is subtracted because the length should not include the chunk name.

```
  Join[pngData, IntegerDigits[Length[extraData] - 4, 256, 4], 
   extraData,
```

Now, the CRC32 hash is calculated and also turned into a four-byte sequence. Note that both Photoshop and  MS Paint don't seem to check this. Quicktime's ImageViewer OTOH does check it and can be used therefore to verify your code. Finally, the end marker is added back.

```
   IntegerDigits[Hash[FromCharacterCode@extraData, "CRC32"], 256, 4], 
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 73, 69, 78, 68, 174, 66, 96, 130}]
  ]
```

Code for importing the meta data:

```
codeFinder := {___, a : PatternSequence[_, _, _, _], Sequence @@ 
              ToCharacterCode@"iTXtMathematica code", b___} :> 
  Uncompress@FromCharacterCode@Take[{b}, {5, FromDigits[{a}, 256]}]

Import["C:\\Users\\Sjoerd\\Desktop\\Untitled-1.png", "Binary"] /. codeFinder
```

Note that I import as binary. I don't want and need any image conversion. What follows is a bit of pattern matching. The core of which is the chunk name "iTXt" and the keyword "Mathematica code" that I wrote into the file earlier.

The preceding `a : PatternSequence[_, _, _, _]` is used to catch and name the 4 length bytes. After conversion with `FromDigits` again, this is used to take a precise bite out of the data from the remainder of the file that was put into `b`. `FromCharacterCode` converts it to a string again, which is then returned into readable Mathematica code by `Uncompress`.

---

**UPDATE 2**

I tested importing graphics from Word documents. I added the above picture to a DOCX and used the following:

```
Import[
  "C:\\Users\\Sjoerd\\Desktop\\Doc1.docx", 
  {"ZIP", "word\\media\\image1.png", "Binary"}
]  /. codeFinder
```

> Plot[Sin[x^2], {x, -3, 3}]

Works without a hitch.

Internal file names used by Word can be found thus:

```
Import["C:\\Users\\Sjoerd\\Desktop\\Doc1.docx"]
```

> {"[Content_Types].xml", "_rels\.rels", \
>   "word\_rels\document.xml.rels", "word\document.xml", \
>   "word\theme\theme1.xml", "word\media\image1.png", \
>   "word\media\image2.gif", "word\settings.xml", \
>   "word\webSettings.xml", "word\stylesWithEffects.xml", \
>   "word\styles.xml", "docProps\core.xml", "word\fontTable.xml", \
>   "docProps\app.xml"}

Which is where I found my PNG file imported above.

Comment: upvote from me...very well thought out

Comment: what i don't like is the code. why do you guys do not show the steps of your solution? the code golfing here is just leading to questions that could be answered already. please explain yourself. is there a need for a function when the steps could be solely explained? I'm more interested in steps not in aggregations...to assemble a function is easy enough.

Comment: @stefan I'll try tomorrow. Off to bed now.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps (ab)using `zTXt` or ` tEXt` fields will be preserved in Photoshop as well?  http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11textinfo

Comment: @Ajasja I've thought of that, but there may be many tEXt fields in a file, so you would need to scan all of those for Mathematica code. Export already inserts two tEXt fields in the file. Perhaps this is just a minor inconvenience, but since I only wanted a proof of concept I opted for a private chunk name.

Comment: @ajasja I tried iTXt, but no improvement in Photoshop. It seems to throw away most metadata. MSPaint still works though.

Comment: @Stefan See update.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Would the data stay in tact if you simple displayed the image as a Graphics and then allowed the user to export the image through the right click Save As option?  I am trying to test that right now, but I have little difficulty dissecting what part of the code to change.  Ideally I would like to be able to copy the image into and directly out of mathematica directly into applications like Word(well LibreOffice).

Comment: @liam not clear what you mean. If you mean from Word, yes, that works. I 've tested that. From Mathematica, no, you have to add the meta information somewhere and there isn't an easy way to get into the Save as.. Menu. Or do you mean importing the png with metadata and importing that in Mathematica again and then using Save as? Anyway, I feel we're spending a bit too much time on this answer. You've got your answers and you should take it from there.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries That's cool, thanks for the help.  I think I have it about figured out, I think I can rig something using `putClipboardImage` from http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/copying-an-image-from-the-clipboard-modifying-it-and-returning-it-to-the-clipbo I'll post my finalize results somewhere so others can use it if they want.

Answer (score 23):

When thinking about graphics formats that can be displayed in web browsers and also in Word, the first thing that comes to mind is a rasterized image. **However**, there is one alternative that makes including comments a complete no-brainer: `SVG` (scalable vector graphics).

The way you do it is similar to what cormullion suggested for `EPS`, except that `EPS` of course can't be used on the web. I don't have Word, but according to Google `SVG` can be displayed in Word. And `SVG` can be displayed in a *resolution-independent* fashion by most modern web browsers, too (because it's a vector format).

Since `SVG` files are plain text `XML` documents, comments can be included anywhere in the same way you add them to a web page, by simply enclosing them between `<!--` and `-->`. So I do that below, to embed the plot command `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]` in the exported file.

The advantage of this format is that the inclusion of comments conforms fully to the official standard. I don't have to hack anything, or append stuff behind the end of the data stream, etc.

**Edit**

If you insist on exporting an **Image** (e.g., because the plot is a complicated `Graphicds3D` object), then you can *still* use the `SVG` format by simply replacing the definition of the plot `p` above with

```
p = Rasterize[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], "Image"];
```

**Explanation:**

The way this works is that `ExportString` creates the exact string representing the `SVG` content. Before writing this string to an `SVG` file with `Export["filename.svg", ..., "Text"]` I use `StringReplace` to insert the comment string directly **after** the `SVG` start tag `<svg >`. The comment always starts with the word `***Exported Comment***` so that it can be distinguished from other possible comments (although I don't think that *Mathematica* would on its own add such comments). The end of the comment is uniquely identified by a comment end tag that directly follows `***Exported Comment***`. That is how I recognize the included code in the `StringCases` command.

---

**Updated code as a function with additional options**

Choose the function appropriate for your version of *Mathematica*:

*Mathematica* version 8:

```
Options[svgExport] = {"CommentString" -> "Created by Mathematica", 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, Background -> Automatic};
Clear[svgExport];
svgExport[name_String, gr_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {
   svgCode =
    StringReplace[
       ExportString[
        First@ImportString[
          ExportString[gr, "PDF", 
           Background -> OptionValue[Background]], "PDF"],
        "SVG", Background -> OptionValue[Background]
        ],
       "<svg " ->
        "<svg viewBox='0 0 " <> StringJoin[
          Riffle[#, {" ", "' "}]] <> "width='" <> #[[1]] <> 
         "' height='" <> #[[2]] <> If[
          OptionValue[AspectRatio] === Full,
          "' preserveAspectRatio='none' ", "' "
          ]
       ] &[
     ToString /@ 
      ImageDimensions[
       Rasterize[Show[gr, ImagePadding -> 0], "Image"]]]
   },
  Export[
   name,
   StringReplace[svgCode, 
    RegularExpression["(<svg\\b[^>]*>)"] :> 
     "$1" <> "\n<!-- ***Exported Comment***\n" <> 
      OptionValue["CommentString"] <> 
      "\n***Exported Comment*** -->"],
   "Text"
   ]
  ]
```

*Mathematica* version 10:

```
Options[svgExport] = {"CommentString" -> "Created by Mathematica", 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, Background -> Automatic};
Clear[svgExport];
svgExport[name_String, gr_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{svgCode = 
    StringReplace[
       ExportString[
        First@ImportString[
          ExportString[gr, "PDF", 
           Background -> OptionValue[Background]], "PDF"], "SVG", 
        Background -> OptionValue[Background]], 
       "<svg " -> 
        "<svg " <> 
         If[OptionValue[AspectRatio] === Full, 
          " preserveAspectRatio='none' ", " "]] &[
     ToString /@ 
      ImageDimensions[
       Rasterize[Show[gr, ImagePadding -> 0], "Image"]]]}, 
  Export[name, 
   StringReplace[svgCode, 
    RegularExpression["(<svg\\b[^>]*>)"] :> 
     "$1" <> "\n<!-- ***Exported Comment***\n" <> 
      OptionValue["CommentString"] <> "\n***Exported Comment*** -->"],
    "Text"]]
```

In order to make the exported `SVG` compatible with external viewers when exporting from *Mathematica* version 8, I handle the dimensions of the graphics more explicitly by adding them to the `<svg>` tag in two forms: as a `viewBox` and as a `width`/`height` attribute. This allows the `SVG` to be scaled better in web browsers, and it also helps tools like *ImageMagick* `convert` recognize the image dimensions. These things are just added for convenience, and for the same reason I now treat the included "Code" as an option named `"CommentString"`.

In *Mathematica* version 10.1, the `viewbox` is already correctly included in the `Export`, so that version requires fewer modifications in the exported file.

---

So the usage of this export function is as follows:

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];

svgExport["plot.svg", p, 
 "CommentString" -> "Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,2 Pi}]"]

(* ==> "plot.svg" *)

StringCases[Import["plot.svg", "Text"], 
 "<!-- ***Exported Comment***" ~~ Shortest[code__] ~~ 
   "***Exported Comment*** -->" -> code]

(*
==> {"
 Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,2 Pi}]
 "}
*)
```

Additional options for `exportSVG` are

- `AspectRatio -> Full` to allow the `SVG` to scale independently in horizontal and vertical directions. This is used in [another answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25916/245), where you can see the effects of this option.
- `Background -> None` to suppress the default (white) background of the exported plot

Comment: uff. sometimes the most most obvious is so near...i pretty like your solution, because it is so simple and again i've to confess to missed the wood from the trees. upvote!

Comment: I always forget about SVG - it never seemed to take off (probably due to Internet Explorer not supporting it).

Comment: I would consider this to be the best solution, except the exported svg's don't seem to be able to be imported by Inkscape.  Basically I am importing and exporting images(svgs into to Inkscape) so they can be printed out.  Keeping track of all the code for each image is impossible though.

Comment: On my Mac, when I drag any SVG onto Inkscape, it opens fine, and I can print it too. Sometimes there are font problems, so you may want to adapt [this font outlining approach](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1286/245) to your graphics, or use `Rasterize` before exporting (as I mentioned above). Inkscape development seems to have been quite slow lately, so I don't know if there's a Windows specific problem with its import abilities. But you can also drag an `SVG` onto Firefox and print from there...

Comment: @Jens Opening the svg file does work fine.  Unfortunately, if I select the svg to copy and paste into another svg file nothing happens.  Additionally if I go to File->Import and select the svg nothing appears to be imported.  It appears there is some sort of height issue, when importing svgs.  I am looking to be able to group multiple images in the same svg file, so then they can easily be printed out.

Comment: Maybe the problem you're seeing has to do with the fact that the bounding box is wrong when importing into Inkscape. That can be fixed by specifying an explicit `ImageSize` in the `SVG` export. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Sometimes the imported `SVG` (when its bounding box is too large) gets pushed off to one of the corners far outside the Inkscape artboard, so you have to scroll around to find it. With the `ImageSize` export option, I don't see this problem and can import fine.

Comment: It's probably better to use `Shortest[code_]`, just in case there are other comments in the file even though you're adding it to the end of the file before the closing tag (comments could've been added later). Alternately, you could use an end marker as `***CODE*** -->`

Comment: @rm-rf Good point - better safe than sorry. I decided to just do it that way (with both `***Code***` and `</svg>` added at the end).

Comment: @Jens Yes adding the `ImageSize` attribute does solve the problem.  Also I think it would be better to put the comment at the beginning of the file after the doctype `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>`.  I see 2 reasons to do this 1) if you open the file in a text editor you immediately see the data 2) If someone edits the the svg in something like Inkscape although the comments are left in tact, the new objects get appended to the ended of the file.  Having new objects appends after the comment and before `</svg>` breaks your current code.

Comment: Sure, that sounds reasonable. Can I leave that modification up to you, or do you want me to edit the answer? Ultimately, I'd say if someone edits an exported file externally without knowing what they're doing, there's no way to **guarantee** that the comments will be preserved anyway. It's the same exact thing with **all the other answers**. So at some point this becomes an open-ended problem.

Comment: OK, I've put the comment string near the beginning. I also added a lot of other features to make the SVG more compatible with other applications. In particular, I also convert text to outlines before exporting so that font problems in Inkscape and Illustrator are avoided.

Answer (score 13):

EPS files are easily hacked in the same way that [Simon's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25789/61) did for PNG. The passenger text happily sits at the end, after the %EOF marker.

```
text = ExampleData[{"Text", "AliceInWonderland"}];

SetOptions[OpenWrite, PageWidth -> Infinity, FormatType -> OutputForm];

StringReplace[
  ExportString[l, "EPS"], 
    {"\t" -> " ", 
     "%EOF" -> "%EOF\n%" <> text}] 
  >> "test2.eps"
```

and later retrieved with something like:

```
StringCases[Import["test2.eps", "Text"], "%EOF\n%" ~~ text__ -> text]
```

This is similar to a technique used by applications such as Macromedia's FreeHand, which embedded the source of the document inside the EPS rendition of it.

Comment: it would be more natural for this data to be just a comment in the metadata section in the beginning of the eps.

Answer (score 12):

Some image file formats such as PNG and JPG can tolerate extra data at the end of the file, so you could simply write your original code into the image file. Of course this won't survive unless the file is completely unaltered - so for example loading the file into an image viewer and saving under a new name will wipe out the extra data.

I have confirmed that a Word 2010 .docx file will preserve the original file, though to get it back you have to extract it from the Word file using a zip utility rather than exporting it from within Word. I don't know if its possible with the older .doc format.

Anyway, despite the limitations I thought might be worth sharing:

```
attachCode[file_String, expr_] := Block[{stream},
  stream = OpenAppend[file];
  WriteString[stream, "Embedded Code:", Compress @ expr];
  Close[stream]]

extractCode[file_String] := Uncompress @ Last @ StringSplit[
    FromCharacterCode @ BinaryReadList @ file, "Embedded Code:"]
```

For example, attaching the evaluation notebook to a PNG image:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

```
Export["test.png", %];

attachCode[%, NotebookGet @ EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

If you download the picture above, you should be able to do this:

```
extractCode["AVRgu.png"] // CreateDocument
```

Comment: Seems to work well - could be useful!

Comment: Another way to extract the original files from word, and probably without changing them, is to do a save as web page (a folder is created with all the images)

Comment: @P.Fonseca You can import the graphics files hidden in a docx file straight from within Mathematica. See update 2 in my answer.

Answer (score 11):

### Embedding Code into an Image

*(Thank god there is Mr. McLoone with his creative mind)*

Say for instance we have a plot:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

To generate an image file:

```
Export["~/plot.png", Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]; 
image = Import["~/plot.png"]; DeleteFile["~/plot.png"];
```

(is there a shortcut for this?)

**Edit** (thank you to rm -rf)

miss the wood for the trees:

```
image = Rasterize[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]];
```

**Edit end**

If we say now, that we use for every color channel the least significant bit to embed the code, we first have to create a truncated variant of the original
image forcing strictly 8-bits per channel:

```
truncImage = BitAnd[ImageData[image, "Byte"], 2^^11111110];
```

Next we have to convert the code into a sequence of bits and insert each of them into those empty bits; padding the rest with zeros:

```
code = PadRight[
    Flatten[IntegerDigits[ToCharacterCode@Compress["Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,2Pi}]"], 2,8]],     
    Apply[Times, Dimensions[ImageData[image, "Byte"]]]];
```

Now we have to merge the truncated image with *code*:

```
codeImage = Image[truncImage + Fold[Partition, code, 
 Reverse@Rest[Dimensions[ImageData[image, "Byte"]]]], "Byte"];
```

Now the code is embedded into that image. In order to extract the code, we've to reverse the process:

```
secCode = FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ (Partition[
 Flatten@BitAnd[ImageData[codeImage, "Byte"], 1], 8]);
```

and then:

```
Uncompress@FromCharacterCode[secCode]
```

=> Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,2Pi}]

or:

```
Uncompress@FromCharacterCode[secCode] // ToExpression
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Here's a way to actually embed the code as part of the image itself. First, let's find some important code we need to save:

```
expr = x^2 + 3;
```

Now compress it and turn it into a string of numbers.

```
cf = Compress@expr;
data = ToCharacterCode[cf]
```

Load in an image and embed the compressed data into the image, then save as a new image.

```
lena = ColorConvert[Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"], "Grayscale"];
imgData = ImageData[lena];
{r, c} = Dimensions[imgData];
imgData[[All, 1]] = N[PadRight[data, r]/255];
newLena = Image[imgData];
Export["lenaPlus.png", newLena]
```

If you look closely, you'll see the first column (on the left) has been changed, this is the data.

[image]

To get the data back, do it in reverse:

```
imported = Import["lenaPlus.png"];
imgData = ImageData[imported];
getCode = imgData[[All, 1]];
Uncompress@FromCharacterCode[Round[255 getCode]]
```

and the answer is:

```
3 + x^2
```

Of course, this isn't really ready for prime time.. to make it generally useful you'd want to embed in color images (rather than just grayscale) and you'd want to add columns to the image (rather than replacing them as above) but the essential idea is here. I would anticipate that this kind of procedure should be robust to simple reading and saving operations in any literal image format (.tif, .png, .gif, .bmp), but it would surely be destroyed in any kind of lossy compression scheme like jpg.

Comment: I don't really see any significant advantage of this over taking the least significant bit of each pixel as in: http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/07/08/doing-spy-stuff-with-mathematica/

Comment: Ajasja - one possibile advantage would be that you do not need to change the picture (assuming you implemented adding columns instead of throwing away the first column). You could get the exact picture back by simply throwing away the added code, whereas in the link, it destroys the LSB of the image. Probably not a large advantage though.

Comment: @Ajasja I don't know enough about the formats, but this solution could probably be modified in some way so that the data could like be extracted even if the image is exported as a different format then is was originally imported.  For example the data might likely stay intact if it is converted form png->jpeg or png->gif because they are physical pixels

Comment: @liam the data will most probably not survive a png -> jpg conversion as this is a lossy transformation.

Answer (score 10):

Anyone is welcome to edit this answer or the wiki question as necessary.

## Compatibility Table For Answers

--------------[Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25759#answer-25835)
..|..[Bill](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25759#answer-25793)
..|..[Sjoerd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25759#answer-25827)
..|..[Simon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25759#answer-25789)
..|..[corm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25759#answer-25828)
..|..[Stefan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25759#answer-25819)

```
no-end  | Y    | _   | Y      | Y      | _     | _ 
MSPaint | .    | Y   | Y      | .      | .     | Y  
 psd    | .    | Y   | .      | .      | .     | Y  
 svg    | Y    | .   | .      | .      | .     | _
 doc    | Y    | Y   | Y      | P      | Y     | Y  
 odp    | .    | .   | .      | .      | .     | _
convert | .    | .   | .      | .      | .     | _
```

Y - Yes  . - No   _- means unknown or uncertain

P - can't export the image using export dialog.  Must extract image from format

Sjoerd - It appears Windows strips metadata when you copy and paste an image from something like a webbrowser

```
Name    | The image can be....
------------------------------------
no-end  | has no-end(size restriction) to the amount of data that can be encoded 
MS Paint| imported/exported from MS Paint without losing info
.psd    | imported/exported from photoshop without losing info
.svg    | imported/exported from inkscape .svg without losing info
.doc    | imported/exported from word .doc without losing info
.odp    | imported/exported form libreoffice .odp format
convert | converted to other formats (lossy or lossless) w/o losing info
```

Comment: you have to define the conversion type (SVG->JPG, PNG->JPG etc.) otherwise that row doesn't make much sense. Also, what do you mean by Photoshop import/export? Do you want to export to Photoshop's native format (PSD)?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I was originally going to put separate rows for different format types SVG->JPG, PNG->JPG etc. but thought putting the types in the box might work better, or asterisks * with descriptions below the table if the answers are to long.  Feel free to do whatever you think we will the best.

Comment: I don't get the P in the .doc line. I can right-click the picture and do a save as... from the context menu. The metadata of the resulting picture can be extracted straight away. The direct import from within Mathematica that I demonstrated in my answer is an extra convenience, not a kludge.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries That is what I get for just glancing over the questions.  :P Fixed.

Comment: IMO it is better to put this information into the question and then flag it to be un-CWed, rather than to write an answer that isn't. BTW, I cannot understand what "no-end" means, nor "edit" (what is an "appropriate" program?).

Comment: @OleksandrR. Multiple people have been edditting the table.  Looking at it now the `Edit` at least from my understanding is basically a duplicate (and also quiet ambiguous) of the `import/export` lines.   I will delete the line.  `No-end` just means there is no limit to the size of the code you can embed.  For example Technically metadata has a 4GB limit to its embed data.