# How do I incorporate metadata using Export?

Tags: graphics, export, options

I have

```
Export["file.png",codeThatMakesAGraphicsObject[],"PNG"];
```

and want to embed some specific metadata information. Is there a simple way to do that?

---

Note that this code already (automatically, apparently) includes metadata information for "Horizontal resolution", "Vertical resolution", "Software used", and "Date and time of digitizing", and I don't want to disturb that with any fields I add.

Comment: You can't have Exif in PNG. The image has to be JPG or TIF

Comment: and I don't think EXIF works in Export anyway. There was a question about this on Wolfram communities recently...

Comment: @rm-rf: Good point. Editing to change "EXIF" to "metadata".

Comment: Maybe this approach would be helpful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25759/embed-code-into-image