# Problem When Trying to Export Graphics with Transparency to SVG

Tags: graphics, export, opacity, svg-format

I'm trying to export a graph as a graphic to an SVG file with transparent background. When the background is specified as a color (or unspecified), it works just fine. When the background is specified as `None`, it offsets the graphic down and to the right a bit and ends of cutting off part of the graphic.

```
g = CompleteGraph[7];
g = GraphicsGrid[{{g}}];
Export["good.svg", g, Background -> Pink];
Export["bad.svg", g, Background -> None];
```

Transparency works perfectly as expected when the graphic is exported to PNG.
Is this a bug, or am I just missing something here?

I'm running Mathematica 9.0.0.0 on Linux 64-bit.

Here's a screenshot of what I am seeing when I open the bad.svg in the gnome image viewer (with some style changes made to the graph for visibility). Note that the image is cut off on the bottom and on the right. When I open bad.svg in chromium or in firefox, it appears fine.

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you please detail your OS and *Mathematica* version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I do see a difference between the contents of `bad.svg` when I export with version 8.0.4 and 9.0.1, the `svg` is displayed in exactly the same way by `Google Chrome`. The display **does** indeed show a white background in `Safari`, though, when exported from *Mathematica* 8.0.4 on OS X. So we could now argue whether this is the fault of the browser, or the fault of *Mathematica*. I think it is indeed a problem with *Mathematica*'s `Export` in version 8.0.4.

What happens is that there is an unnecessary line in the exported `SVG` file, located at a nominally inaccessible position:

> `<rect fill='rgb(100%,100%,100%)' stroke='none' x='-2.2518e+15' y='-2.2518e+15' width='4.5036e+15' height='4.5036e+15' />`

This is apparently recognized by Google Chrome as something that can't be displayed. But in Safari, it is in fact displayed as a white background. I checked this by embedding the file in an `HTML` document with

> `<body style="background:gray;"><img src="bad.svg">`

When I remove the offending `rect` from the `SVG` file, the display in Safari is fixed:

[image: bad good]

Since I can't be sure that this faulty line is *always* generated the same way when exporting `SVG` with no background, I can at this point only recommend removing this line from the `SVG` file *manually*. It's line 6 in the exported file.

In version 9.0.1, I don't see this line in the exported file, and there is no white background in any browser that I have tried.

**Edit to address sizing**

As mentioned in the comment, there is a problem in that the size of the exported `SVG` isn't always correctly identified. To fix this, you can use the function `svgExport` from [my answer to "Embed Code Into Image"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25835/245). It makes the necessary replacements in the exported code.

Comment: For me, the transparency works fine in both google-chrome and firefox when I embed it into an `HTML` file, but the image is cut off again in firefox (much more so than in the gnome image viewer screenshot above). Also, using Mathematica 9.0.0.0, my `Bad.SVG` file doesn't have a line like you describe. There is not line starting with `<rect fill=` but instead on line 6 I've got `<polyline fill=`. Link the the `SVG` [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=61tA4rfc).

Comment: I agree about Firefox, but it can be easily fixed with `<img src="bad.svg" style="width:360px;height:360px;"`. It's unrelated to the background issue, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12830897/915703). So basically, one should call this a bug that has apparently been fixed in version 9.0.1 but not in 9.0.0.

Comment: For the Firefox problem, I added a link to my answer that fixes this issue.