# Defining a Function to Modify the Image Data of an Image

Tags: image-processing, image

So say I have certain data that I want to add to Image Data of an Image

How can I write a function in Mathematica that can do that?

Edit:
My Purpose is to input data in an Image Data so that I can retrieve it later
It doesn't matter how it's added there are no conditions I just need to be able to add it and retrieve it later

[image: here is the image]

Comment: How to "add"?You should give more information for your question.Provide your data and your image,please.

Comment: @yode the data could be anything aka any string as for the image I provided it. thank you.

Comment: But I don't know where you want to "input" and how you will retrieve.

Comment: I wanna input my string in the "Output" of the Built-In Function ImageData when I apply it to my image

Comment: So say I Input my image in mathematica and store it in some variable A then Apply ImageData to A and get the output.. I want to put some matrix in there with the ability to retrieve it later

Comment: Are you talking about [metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata)?

Comment: not really what I wanna do is re generate the image in mathematica with the Built-In function Image with a matrix of importance to me in it so that I can retrieve it later (the matrix) with some function (what I am asking for)

Comment: As your [lastest response](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133369/defining-a-function-to-modify-the-image-data-of-an-image#comment359766_133369),maybe my answer is off topic.Since this,what's meaning of your [this comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133369/defining-a-function-to-modify-the-image-data-of-an-image#comment359761_133369)?

Comment: @yode actually it's On Topic :D thank you so much I can't even thank you enough :( nevermind about that comment you gave me exactly what I need.

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25759/862)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Perhaps it's duplicate post again,but this post should make more clear I think.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This method based on [Steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography).Hope to help.

I suppose you have this string:

```
string = ExampleData[{"Text", "USConstitution"}]
```

> PREAMBLE We the People of the United States, in Order to form a more
>   perfect Union, establish Justice, insure domestic Tranquility, provide
>   for the common defence, promote the general Welfare, and secure the
>   Blessings of Liberty to ourselves and our Posterity, do ordain and
>   establi....

And you have such image

```
img=ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]
```

[image]

### "Add" your information to image

```
AddToImage[image_, information_] := 
 Module[{imageData, dim, residueBit, imageCapacity, informationSize, 
   bitNumber, carrierImageData, informationBin}, 
  imageData = ImageData[image, "Byte"]; dim = Dimensions[imageData]; 
  residueBit = Mod[Times @@ dim, 16]; 
  imageCapacity = Times @@ dim - residueBit; 
  informationSize = Length[ToCharacterCode[information]]*16 + 2; 
  bitNumber = Quotient[informationSize, imageCapacity]; 
  carrierImageData = 
   Fold[BitClear[#1, #2] &, Flatten[imageData], Range[0, bitNumber]]; 
  informationBin = 
   Join[IntegerDigits[bitNumber, 2, 2], 
    Flatten[PadLeft[#, 16] & /@ 
      IntegerDigits[ToCharacterCode[information], 2]]]; 
  If[bitNumber > 2, 
   "Your amount of information is too big for encryption.You should \
get a larger image or decrease your information size.", 
   Image[ArrayReshape[
     BitOr[PadRight[
       FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ 
        Flatten[Reverse[
          Partition[informationBin, imageCapacity, imageCapacity, 
           1, {}]], {2}], imageCapacity + residueBit], 
      carrierImageData], dim], "Byte"]]]

informationImage=AddToImage[img, string]
```

[image]

Well,it's seem nothing to happen.Actually I "input" a USConstitution in it.Of course,the image just can take a limit size information.And if you want to export this image to share to other people,you must use **.png**,**.tiff** or other uncompressed format.Otherwise you cannot retrieve your information any more.

### Extract that data

```
ExtractInformation[image_] := 
 Module[{imageData = ImageData[image, "Byte"], residueBit, 
   informationCode, informationCodeLen, outBitNum}, 
  outBitNum = FromDigits[BitGet[Flatten[imageData][[;; 2]], 0], 2]; 
  residueBit = Mod[Times @@ Dimensions[imageData], 16]; 
  informationCode = 
   Partition[
    Flatten[BitGet[
         Flatten[imageData][[;; 
           Times @@ Dimensions[imageData] - residueBit]], #] & /@ 
       Range[0, outBitNum]][[3 ;;]], 16]; 
  informationCodeLen = 
   SparseArray[informationCode]["NonzeroPositions"][[-1, 1]]; 
  FromCharacterCode[
   FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ informationCode[[;; informationCodeLen]]]]

ExtractInformation[informationImage]
```

> PREAMBLE We the People of the United States, in Order to form a more
>   perfect Union, establish Justice, insure domestic Tranquility, provide
>   for the common defence, promote the general Welfare, and secure the
>   Blessings of Liberty to ourselves and our Posterity, do ordain and
>   establish this Co...