# Hiding a message in a photo using Mathematica

Tags: image-processing, image

So, this is a problem that me and my friends are facing while doing a project for school.

Our idea is the following. Given a certain photo we want to be able to hide a message behind it. Our approach was the following.

We start by using the command **Import** to get the image to *Mathematica*. Then we use the command **ImageData** to extract the list that contains the pixels in the image.

Then, our approach was to identify a sequence which was not present in those digits. For example, there is no number that is of the form 0,1770... Then we could save the information in these types of numbers.

So, we generate these numbers and then, with the command **ReplacePixelValue** we were able to replace the pixels in the image. At this point we though that our work was done. But it happens that the information was not preserved with the **Export** of the coded image.

Our main questions are:

1. Is it true, by any chance, that exporting a file do not preserve the information? And
2. What would be the best approach to attain our goal?

Thank you som much for your attention. Have a nice day.

**UPDATE**

By using the **ReplacePart** in the list of pixels instead of ReplacePixelValue, I managed to obtain the correct list with the correct substitution of values. Although, when I ask for the image of this new list (by using the command **Image**) the values are edited. When I ask for a value that was substituted by me, the value is no longer there.

Comment: What format does the image have? If it's JPEG or another lossy format, the compression upon export will potentially alter the precise pixel values

Comment: Yes it is a JPEG file

Comment: Is there any way to avoid that problem? Perhaps by choosing another formate for the image?

Comment: If you export to PNG, then you should be fine in that regard (i.e the pixel data that you export will be exactly the pixel data that you import again)

Comment: @LukasLang thank you for the suggestion. Let me try that if it works :)

Comment: I realised something that can also be a problem, so I will update right now the question

Comment: You may find [`ResourceFunction["SteganographyInsert"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SteganographyInsert)  interesting. To see what it does, the WFR page lets you download the source notebook.

Comment: What you're doing is called [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography). Look at [Doing Spy Stuff with Mathematica](https://blog.wolfram.com/2010/07/08/doing-spy-stuff-with-mathematica/) and [SteganographyInsert](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SteganographyInsert) and [SteganographyExtract](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SteganographyExtract).

Comment: @flinty that is indeed interesting. Thank you som much! I will check it now :)

Comment: Without seeing your code, it will be difficult to help you any further

Comment: Not the same (I think), but related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25759/embed-code-into-image

Answer (score 4):

First, the problem with exporting. There are formats that are lossless and formats that will change the content. Lossless picture format are e.g.: BMP, PNG or RAW. On the other hand, e.g. JPEG will change the content.

Now how to hide some message in a picture? Here is a way to do this:

Idea: Change every pixel of the picture by 0 or 1 according to the message in binary form.

First convert the picture into an array of bytes and the message into a binary array. For convenience prepend the original message length in binary to the message array. Then add the message array to first part of the picture array with the same length. Then convert the message array back to a picture.

Here is the code that does this:

```
encode[pic_, message_] := Module[{len, d, dims, mess, df},
  d = ImageData[pic, "Byte"];
  dims = d // Dimensions;
  mess = IntegerDigits[ToCharacterCode[message], 2, 8] // Flatten;
  mess = Join[IntegerDigits[Length[mess], 2, 16], mess];
  df = Flatten[d];
  If[(len = Length[mess]) > Length[df], Print["Message too long"]; 
   Return[]];
  df[[;; len]] += mess;
  Image[ArrayReshape[df, dims]/255.]
  ]

decode[pic_, pic0_] := Module[{by, byc, len},
  byc = ImageData[pic, "Byte"] // Flatten;
  by = ImageData[pic0, "Byte"] // Flatten;
  mess = byc - by;
  len = FromDigits[mess[[;; 16]], 2];
  mess = mess[[17 ;; 17 + len]];
  FromCharacterCode@FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ Partition[mess, 8] // 
   StringJoin
  ]
```

We may test this using a picture from "ExampleData":

```
pic = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}];
coded = encode[pic, "Hello World"];
decode[coded, pic]

(* "Hello World" *)
```

And there is little difference in the images:

```
pic
code
```

[image]