# Problem displaying "/" correctly in exported svg file of Plot in Mathematica 8

Tags: plotting, svg-format

In a plot, I use "/" on the axes labels to denote units. E.g. "t/s" meaning time in seconds. I believe this is pretty standard in Physics.

```
Plot[5 Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesLabel -> {"t/s", "V/V"}]
```

When I export this as an svg file in Mathematica 8, which I use to post on a website, the "/" gets replaced by a space or a square or something else, depending on the web browser. I have tried Google Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer in Windows 10, 64 bit. Try clicking on the link below. You may have to zoom in to see it clearly.

[Plot svg link](http://breadboardadventures.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Plot-Test.svg)

So how can I display "/" correctly?

Comment: Safari 8 on OS X displays "/" correctly. It might thus be helpful if you provided information about your OS and browser (it might be a bug in your browser, not Mathematica)

Comment: You could try my answer to [How can I get Mathematica to include size information in exported SVG?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25916/245) because it fixes other problems, too. It might work for you because it also outlines all fonts (i.e., draws them as vector graphics). This can increase the file size but usually eliminates font problems entirely.

Comment: Thanks @Jens that works! However, I found that when the plot has only a positive y-axis, the bottom of the number ticks get chopped off as in here: [graph](http://breadboardadventures.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Vlineint2.svg). Try zooming in. But when I added the option `TicksStyle -> Medium` in Plot, it works well as in here [graph with Tickstyle->Medium](http://breadboardadventures.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Vlineint.svg).

Comment: Try adding some [`ImagePadding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html)

Comment: Indeed, there is a lack of padding in your first plot. But I think @Sascha has the right suggestion to fix that.